# How can I align subplot images with different size in matlab

Tags: matlab, alignment, subplot

I have plotted three sub-images on a plot with Matlab as Figure 1 shows, you can see their titles and images are not aligned in a line. I want to plot a figure as Figure 2 or 3 where at least the titles are aligned. How can I do that? thank you.

Figure 1
[image: Matlab subplots]

Figure 2
[image: Matlab aligned subplots2]

Figure 3
[image: Matlab aligned subplots1]

Comment: please add code to your example. Are you using the MatLab'subplot' command? which command are you using for presenting the image?

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is that there is no way (that I know of) to align subplots. You could however manually give the exact positions and size of each image so that means you can compute the aligned locations manually.

It will be something along these lines:

```
y = .8; % vertical location stays fixed

subplot('Position', [.1 y width1 height1]);
imagesc(img1);
title('1');

[s1 s2] = size(img2);
subplot('Position', [.4 y width2 height2]);
imagesc(img2);
title('2');

[s1 s2] = size(img3);
subplot('Position', [.7 y width3 height3]);
imagesc(img3);
title('3');
```

Comment: I didn't understand, please give specific example. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the answer I want.